# C# code for reset password Amazon Cognito User Pool

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, passwords, amazon-cognito

I am currently making an Desktop Application and using Amazon Cognito for Authentication and Registration. But I dont know how to write code for Reset Password. Please help. I need the code for resetting password.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. This is a code debugging platform and not a place where people write your code. Please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide the code you have created while attempting to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A simple search led me to their library. You should find your answer there.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html